# Python Merge function isn't working as result appear as "Nan"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, merge

I have two dataframes that I need to merge but the results kept sending (NAN) values. I changed the `how` but still no impact.

**Used Function**

```
PG =pd.merge(left=PG.astype(str), right=SCH.astype(str), how='left',left_on='Merged', right_on='Merged' , suffixes=('', '_remove'))
```

**DF 1**

```
                       Merged
0    140042022-05-09 00:00:00
1     27942022-05-10 00:00:00
2    140042022-05-11 00:00:00
3    140062022-05-10 00:00:00
4    140062022-05-11 00:00:00
..                        ...
```

**DF2**

```
                             Merged Today-Shift
0      147212022-03-01 00:00:00    0.291667
1      147212022-03-02 00:00:00    0.291667
2      147212022-03-03 00:00:00    0.291667
3      147212022-03-04 00:00:00    0.291667
4      147212022-03-05 00:00:00         OFF
...                         ...         ...
```

**Result**

```
        Today-Shift
0           NaN
1           NaN
2           NaN
3           NaN
4           NaN
```

Comment: How do you want to merge? Output only the common rows? What is the expected output of the given `DF1` and `DF2`?

Answer (score 1):

According to Pandas documentation on `merge`, we can perform any of the `{‘left’, ‘right’, ‘outer’, ‘inner’, ‘cross’}` join on two dataframes. If we want to perform inner join on the `df_2` with `df_1`, it will result in only the common rows among these two dataframes. Here is an example of inner join on two dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Merged': ["140042022-05-09 00:00:00",
               "27942022-05-10 00:00:00",
               "147212022-03-01 00:00:00"]
})

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Merged': ["147212022-03-01 00:00:00",
               "147212022-03-02 00:00:00",
               "147212022-03-03 00:00:00"],
    'Today-Shift': [0.291667, 0.291667, "OFF"]
})

df_3 = df_2.merge(df_1, how='inner', left_on='Merged', right_on='Merged')
print(df_3)
```

**Output:**

```
                     Merged Today-Shift
0  147212022-03-01 00:00:00    0.291667
```

**References:**

- [Pandas documentation on merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)